# How to access process instance id of process inside tasks of activity

Tags: java, activiti

I want to access the process instance Id of currently running process, inside the task of activity. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: @Aaron OP isn't asking about the OS process ID of the jvm. Activiti is a business process system, and a process instance ID is a business process concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can get process instance id of current process by using [DelegateExecution](https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/delegate/DelegateExecution.html) or [DelegateTask](https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/delegate/DelegateTask.html).
You can find many example on how to use it in the [Activiti User Guide](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/).